# how to set comment as unread/read with multiple users

Tags: php, css, phpmyadmin

i have a development blog in my project.i want add facility of set comment as unread for user until he/she see the comment.
suppose admin post a comment so for all users in that project should get that comment as unread

can anyone help

```
should i use $_SESSION or i have to use database tables?
```

Comment: i want it in php code...can any one help....i m totally stuck

Comment: You have to try something with PHP . Then ask for help.Use database tables.What happen if session expired after certain amount of time?.Obviously you will lost the data.

Comment: thanks...! i tried many things.i  have created tables with 3 columns comment_id,update_id and user_id.when should i insert values in this table?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Database. Create 3 tables at least: `user`, `comment`, `userReadComment` since user read comment is a multi-to-multi relationship.

Comment: i have all these three tables...!in userReadComment i uses user_id,comment_id and update_id...!  but i cant understand when should i insert data in userreadcomment

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a proper design of the project.

What do you mean by :

> i want it in php code...can any one help....i m totally stuck

?

You have to use Database only. It is as simple as this, once you have the comment table where you refer its ID and along with that you do user ID... if it is present, its read else, it isn't!

Or

You can set an enum of read or unread.

Can you show what have you done so far?

Comment: i m inserting comments..!and fetch it from database and show it..!  now i want that if admin add a comment then it will be unread for all other user..!  i hve comment table with comment_id,project id,update_id,comment,comment_date